# Help find Lego number for large Technic F1 Ferrari

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Help! I'm trying to find the Lego number, and missing parts for the rear wing etc.

[image: F1 Ferrari]

Answer (score 4):

This is set 8386 Ferrari F1 Racer 1:10.

[image: 8386 Box]

It's hard to tell from your photo exactly what is missing. Obviously the rear spoiler is missing, but there may be several other smaller elements missing.

[Brickset](https://brickset.com/sets/8386-1/Ferrari-F1-Racer-1-10) and LEGO.com both have the full instructions, so the best way to determine what is missing is probably to walk through those. Here they are:

https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/4280172.pdf

You can find the [complete parts list](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=8386-1) for this set on Bricklink if you'd like to order any replacement parts.

Comment: Hello, Thank you jncraton for the info! As well as for the edits guys appreciated it much. I have also found out it can be converted to RC. Does anyone knows how to do this? I hope there is an instructions manual also.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad that was helpful. In terms of the RC conversion, you should ask that as a new question so it gets more visibility and can be answered fully.